# Not possible to include file from Boost library (xml_parser.hpp)

Tags: c++, boost

I have created a test project for myself to test a Boost Library. I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 Community(/std:c++20, v142) and Boost 1.78.0. I can compile and run the code on https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/more/getting_started/windows.html (4 Build a Simple Program Using Boost). However, I cannot run the code below. Problem is xml_parser.hpp. Can't do much with the error messages unfortunately. Haven't modified xml_parser.hpp either. The attached link shows the various error messages.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
   
    return 0;
}
```

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQfFg.png)

Error       C3083   'Str': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type              HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  38

Error       C2039   'value_type': is not a member of 'std'                      HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  38

Error       C3646   'Ch': unknown override specifier                            HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  38

Error       C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int        HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  38

Error       C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Ch'                               HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  40

Error       C3646   'indent_char': unknown override specifier                       HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  49

Error       C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int        HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  49

Error       C3861   'indent_char': identifier not found                         HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  43

Error       C3861   'inchar': identifier not found                          HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  43

Error       C3861   'incount': identifier not found                         HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  44

Error       C3861   'enc': identifier not found                             HelloWorld  c:\boost\boost\property_tree\detail\xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp  45

Comment: Can you please post the complete errors as text and not as screenshot (and not just the IDE's shortcut, but the actual compile output)?
Also: what are your include directories during compilation?

Comment: Hi,
I have added the errors in the original post.

Addtional include directories: C:\boost;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Comment: Please include only boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp and include the preprocessed code (enable it in the compiler options for the source file). Also, what compiler are you using (version and config)?

Comment: ```Str``` is a type template; template classes and functions are not generated, if they are not used for a specific type or instantiated explicitly for that type. 
I still don't get the error messages: usually the compiler is much more verbose and tells you which instantiation caused the issue and t also shows the complete include cascade